# Could SVG be declared with multiple widths?

Tags: html, svg

I am trying to show chevrons one after the other where tip of one chevron attaches to the next chevron's end. These will be used as different buttons.

I tried defining svgs but svgs have a defined width due to which there is gap between tip of chevron #1 chevron #2.

```html
<svg width="165" height="120">
  <a href="#">
    <path d="M 0,0
      L 0,67
      L 130,67
      L 165,34
      L 130,0
      Z"
      fill="#007BFF"/>
  </a>
  </svg>
<svg width="165" height="120" >
  <a href="#" >
    <path d="M 0,0
      L 35,34
      L 0,67
      L 130,67
      L 165,34
      L 130,0
      Z"
      fill="#0000FF" />
  </a>
</svg>
```

Expected: Chevrons attached to one another in one line
Actual: There is gap between chevrons in one line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest is to merge both your anchors in a single <svg>.

You need to make it bigger so that both shapes can fit in, and to either redefine the second path or to move it on the right using transformations:

```html
<svg width="300" height="120">
  <a href="#">
    <path
      d="M 0,0
        L 0,67
        L 130,67
        L 165,34
        L 130,0
        Z"
      fill="#007BFF"/>
  </a>
  <a href="#" >
    <path transform="translate(130, 0)" 
      d="M 0,0
        L 35,34
        L 0,67
        L 130,67
        L 165,34
        L 130,0
        Z"
      fill="#0000FF" />
  </a>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. One piece fan :D

Answer (score 1):

Just give your second SVG a `margin-left` of `-40px`. This will do the trick.

```html
<svg width="165" height="120">
  <a href="#">
    <path d="M 0,0
      L 0,67
      L 130,67
      L 165,34
      L 130,0
      Z"
      fill="#007BFF"/>
  </a>
</svg>

<svg width="165" height="120" style="margin-left: -40px">
  <a href="#" >
    <path d="M 0,0
      L 35,34
      L 0,67
      L 130,67
      L 165,34
      L 130,0
      Z"
      fill="#0000FF" />
  </a>
</svg>
```

Comment: You just broke the first anchor at its arrow-end.

Comment: You can put both paths in the same SVG element